# PostgreSQL wildcard LIKE for any of a list of words

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple list of ~25 words. I have a varchar field in PostgreSQL, let's say that list is `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`. I want to find any row in my table that has any of those words. This will work, but I'd like something more elegant.

```
select *
from table
where (lower(value) like '%foo%' or lower(value) like '%bar%' or lower(value) like '%baz%')
```

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You can use Postgres' [`SIMILAR TO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) operator which supports alternations, i.e.

```
select * from table where lower(value) similar to '%(foo|bar|baz)%';
```

Comment: Regex might speed this up a bit: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql

Comment: How do you know it ? most of documentation I've read says that regex are slower and a LIKE %...

Comment: According to http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/27757 `SIMILAR TO` is internally translated to a regex search

Comment: I think using `lower()` is ineffective because it will first convert each string to lowercase, which is more costly than only a case-insensitive match

Comment: if you are using jpa then same native query can be written as below

`@Query(value = "select * from table_name where  lower(< filter col name >) similar to lower(CONCAT('%', :string, '%')) ", nativeQuery = true)
 List<Object[]> test2(@Param("string") String string);`

Here string = (foo|bar|baz)

Answer (score 386):

PostgreSQL also supports full [POSIX regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
select * from table where value ~* 'foo|bar|baz';
```

The `~*` is for a case insensitive match, `~` is case sensitive.

Another option is to use [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16):

```
select * from table where value  like any (array['%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%']);
select * from table where value ilike any (array['%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%']);
```

You can use ANY with any operator that yields a boolean. I suspect that the regex options would be quicker but ANY is a useful tool to have in your toolbox.

Comment: Interestingly, while both of these methods are more elegant than @chmullig 's solution (so +1), when checking 3 options at least, they execute significantly slower on large tables (91.5 million records in my case). I was seeing a time increase of about 2x when using either of these. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @sage88 I don't know off the top of my head but Erwin Brandstetter might and adding [trigram indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/479863) might help.

Answer (score 31):

Actually there is an operator for that in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE lower(value) ~~ ANY('{%foo%,%bar%,%baz%}');
```

Comment: `~~` is just another name for `like`: ["The operator `~~` is equivalent to `LIKE`, and `~~*` corresponds to `ILIKE`. There are also `!~~` and `!~~*` operators that represent `NOT LIKE` and `NOT ILIKE`, respectively. All of these operators are PostgreSQL-specific."](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE). And `'{%foo%,%bar%,%baz%}'` is the text form of `array['%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%']`.

Comment: So can *ilike* be used with *any* & array in the same way? This looks clean if there is no need for fancy regex. Or is it going to be translated to regex internally anyway?

Comment: @mlt That is a good question, reading the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) does not provide explicit answer. `SIMILAR TO` does convert into Regular Expression, `~` operator stands for POSIX Regular Expression, but this is not clear for `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

One 'elegant' solution would be to use full text search: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/textsearch.html. Then you would use full text search queries.

Comment: Downvote, because this is only a link that would be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

All currently supported versions (9.5 and up) allow pattern matching in addition to `LIKE`.

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html