# Using "similar to" or "~*" in jpql

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, playframework, jpql

I am using `postgresql` with `jpa` in `playframework 2.2`.

I am trying to use `like with in` in my `JPQL` by using `similar to` something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928054/postgresql-wildcard-like-for-any-of-a-list-of-words) thread.

```
select * from table where lower(value) similar to '%(foo|bar|baz)%';
```

I have tried `similar to` and `~*` in my JPQL but both dint work.

On  using `similar to` it gives

```
IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: similar near line 1
```

Is there any way I can use `similar to` or `~*` like functionality apart from using `like` in `JPQL`?

Thanks

Comment: And if you'd have read any JPQL reference you would know that this is not valid JPQL so I don't get the idea of ramming whatever SQL into JPQL. JPQL does have "LIKE"; an internet search would show details

Comment: @NeilStockton: `like` is something completely different than `similar to` or `~*`.

Comment: @NeilStockton I know its not valid as of the exception also but I was trying to search some alternative of `similar to`apart from using `like`

Comment: @nameless horse, yes I know they are different, but the poiint is there are references to JPQL on the web. And when a query doesn't fit into JPQL you have a "native query" where you can put as much database-specific syntax through as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

There is regex support in EclipseLink, check release note for 2.4:

- http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_regexp.htm
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions

But I don't know if hibernate supports it too. Think it's not part of JPA spec.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but I dint try eclipse link before so I will go throught it,anyway thanks :)