# Case insensitive search using IN operator in Ruby on Rails and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'm new to ROR and trying to implement search in PostgreSQL database using Active Record. I've found that to make search case insensitive I can use `ILIKE` operator  instead of `equals` and `LIKE` but not sure what to do when I need to use `IN` operator.

I'm getting a field name and a collection of values which I need to check and case sensitive search works like that:

```
records = records.where(filter['fieldName'] => filter['value'])
```

where `filter['value']` is an array.

Is there a way to update that line to make it case insensitive?

If no then I believe the only way is to loop through that array and split `IN` into many `OR` operations and use `ILIKE` for every single value in that array(however I'm not sure how to use OR with Active Record)?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the "filter" hash coming from. Looks like SQLI prone to me.

Can you store the values already downcased in the DB?
Can you add additional indexes?

Comment: @pascalbetz filter is a part of my custom structure that I send through REST from another app. Unfortunately I need to keep real case in database, but I almost fixed it with below suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
records = records.where('"' + filter['fieldName'] + '"' +
                         " ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )", filter['value'].map {|value| "%#{value}%" })
```

Comment: Btw you should escape special symbols as well, assuming `value` might contain `%`.

Answer (score 4):

```
records.where("lower(#{filter['fieldName']}) in (?)", filter['value'].map(&:downcase))
```

Comment: Looks like your answer is the closest :) `records = records.where('"' + filter['fieldName'] + '"' +" ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )", filter['value'].map {|value| "%#{value}%" })` here is what worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @OlesMalkov you should post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ......

```
records.where("lower(#{filter['fieldName']}) in ?", filter['value'].map(&:downcase))
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: @pascalbetz, not sure how that should work as he is using `=` and not `in`.

Comment: @OlesMalkov you are right. Should be "IN" instead of "=". Or he could use "similar to" as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928054/postgresql-wildcard-like-for-any-of-a-list-of-words