# Query for iLike list in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing an inefficient query as follows:

```
WHERE (Field iLIKE '%cat%' OR Field iLIKE '%dog%' OR Field  iLIKE '%animal%' OR Field  iLIKE '%pet%')
```

whereas what I would like to write is:

```
WHERE Field iLIKE ('%cat%','%dog%','%animal%','%pet%')
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: can use `SIMILAR TO` syntax perhaps

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928054/postgresql-wildcard-like-for-any-of-a-list-of-words

Comment: I tried WHERE (DESCRIPTION similar to '%(cat|dog|animal)%') and it didn't work.  Could you please advise?

Answer (score 20):

You can get the powerful regular expression operators `~` and `~*` for case insensitive:

```
WHERE Field ~* '(cat|dog|animal|pet)'
```

`SIMILAR TO` is case sensitive, so you'd have to do:

```
WHERE Field SIMILAR TO '%([Cc][Aa][Tt]|[Dd][Oo][Gg]|[Aa][Nn][Ii][Mm][Aa][Ll]|[Pp][Ee][Tt])%'
```

`ANY ARRAY` will work too, but the perfomance is worse:

```
WHERE Field ILIKE ANY (array['%cat%','%dog%','%animal%','%pet%'])
```

With some dummy data with 1000000 rows with a BTREE INDEX in `Field`, I get these results:

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╗
║  Operator   ║ Time (secs) ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ ~*          ║ 1.5         ║
║ SIMILAR TO  ║ 1.4         ║
║ ANY ARRAY   ║ 4.0         ║
║ OR OR OR... ║ 4.0         ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select 'cata' ilike any (array['%cat%','%dog%','%animal%','%pet%']);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```