# PostgreSQL wildcard LIKE for any of a list of words returned by Subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is very much like [PostgreSQL wildcard LIKE for any of a list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928054/postgresql-wildcard-like-for-any-of-a-list-of-words), except instead of wanting to match on a static list of words, I want to match on a list of words returned by a subquery.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM people
WHERE name ~* (SELECT concat(last_name, ', ', first_name) 
               FROM other_people) + wildcard in this direction
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
from people
where name like any (
    select concat(last_name, ', ', first_name, '%')
    from other_people
)
```

Comment: Heroic.  Thank you.