# Filtering records based on all members of association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `Story`, which has — and belongs to many — Tags. I'm trying to create functionality to display only certain stories based on the story attributes. I do this by chaining `where()`s:

```
q = Story.where(condition1)
q = q.where(condition2)
```

...et cetera. One of the things I want to be able to filter on is tags, which at first I tried to do as follows:

```
q = q.joins(:tags)
q = q.where(tagCondition1)
q = q.where(tagCondition2)
...
```

However, this only finds stories that have a single tag that matches all conditions. I want to find all stories that have at least one tag that matches each condition. That is, currently if I have the conditions `LIKE %al%` and `LIKE %be%`, it will match a story with the tag `'alpha beta'`; I want it to also match a story with the tag `'alpha'` and the tag `'beta'`.

Comment: What DB? If you are using postgres there are plenty of options - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928054/postgresql-wildcard-like-for-any-of-a-list-of-words

Comment: On the SQL side, you have to join to the same table more than once. Not sure rails handles that situation very well.

Comment: I am already using SIMILAR TO for the text searches, but I'm not sure how it would help here?

Comment: Either split the string and search for the components or use full text search.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the below to match multiple conditions:

```
q.where([tagCondition1, tagCondition2, ...])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HAVING` with a count.

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  def self.with_tags(*tags, min: 1)
    joins(:tags)
      .where(tags: { name: tags })
      .group('story.id')
      .having("count(*) = ?", min)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
params[:tag] = "foo bar baz"
Story.with_tags(params[:tag], *params[:tag].split)
```

Would include stories with any of the tags `["foo bar baz", "foo", "bar", "baz"]`.

Comment: I don't understand this code. What does min represent?

Comment: The minimum number of matches. If you do `Story.with_tags("foo", "bar", "baz", min: 2)` it will only return stories with at least 2 of the 3 tags

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will work incorrectly if one tag matches two or more conditions; this tag will only increase count by 1, even though two conditions matched.

Comment: No - its a left join so it will only return only stories that have at least one of the tags provided in the list. If you set `min: 2`, than you need two tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131803/sql-where-joined-set-must-contain-all-values-but-may-contain-more

Answer (score 0):

The query is wrong. Since you are using AND and you want to match the first OR the second condition. Maybe you should use something like

`where("tags.field like '%al% or tags.field like '%be%'")`

Comment: Well, I thought of that, but the problem there is that then it will find stories that have a tag that matches one condition, even if none of the other conditions are matched at all. I want to match all conditions, just not necessarily in the same tag.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's what I ended up doing: (added for anyone who's googling and has a similar problem):

```
conditions.each do |condition|
  q_part = select('1').from('stories_tags')
  q_part = q_part.where('stories_tags.story_id = stories.id')
  q_part = q_part.where('stories_tags.name SIMILAR TO ?', condition)
  q = q.where("EXISTS (#{q_part.to_sql})")
end
```