# Match a list of patterns using SQL IN and LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-like, sql-in

Is it possible to match a list of patterns in SQL?

I know of the following way to match a single pattern:

```
SELECT * FROM table where title LIKE '%match%'
```

This can be exbanded like;

```
SELECT * FROM table 
where title LIKE '%match%' OR title LIKE '%match2%'
```

... etc

I have a long list of patterns, is it possible to use 'IN' in any way, to make the code more readable?

Something more as this

```
SELECT * FROM table where title LIKE IN (match, match2, match3)
```

or am i forced to write lots of "OR"'s?

Edit: Was using SQL-Alchemy (Python library) to connect to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! There is a way to do it in Microsoft SQL Server.

```
SELECT *
 FROM employees
 WHERE last_name LIKE 'match_'
```

where _ can be any other letter
but also you can be more specific to more complicated patterns

```
 SELECT * FROM titles WHERE title LIKE '[a-t]itanic'
```

Here you will get all those combinations aitanic etc.
But I think that the easiest way to do it is just to match everything as you've said by %text% and applying OR

Comment: Product specific solution to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. My matches unfortunately have nothing in common, one can be like "apples" and another "pies". But thank you anyway! I think ill just go with doing several OR statements after each other.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is postgres you can use something like:

`WHERE title ~~ ANY('{%foo%,%bar%,%baz%}');`

That comes from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928054/postgresql-wildcard-like-for-any-of-a-list-of-words).  I haven't found anything comparable for Azure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL Server (T-SQL), there is no support for `WHERE a LIKE (b, c, d, e)` or similar. However, here is a work-around that gives you the ability to make the list of patterns dynamic and doesn't force you to resort to "OR-chaining" multiple `LIKE` expressions.

```
declare @Fruits table (Name nvarchar(100));

insert @Fruits (Name)
values 
    ('Apple')
    , ('Banana')
    , ('Cherry')
    , ('Pear')
    , ('Strawberry')
    , ('Blackberry')
    , ('Raspberry')
    , ('Pomegranate')
    , ('Plantain')
    , ('Grape')
    , ('Kiwi')
;

-----------------------------------------------------------
-- STATIC - using OR-chaining
-----------------------------------------------------------
select 
    f.Name
from 
    @Fruits f
where 
    f.Name like 'B%'
    or f.Name like '%berry'
;

-----------------------------------------------------------
-- DYNAMIC - using EXISTS
-----------------------------------------------------------
select 
    f.Name
from 
    @Fruits f
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from (values ('B%'), ('%berry')) v (Pattern) 
        where f.Name like v.Pattern escape '\'
    )
;
```

Using the "dynamic" style, you could populate a table of patterns elsewhere, dynamically, and with an arbitrary number of patterns, giving you more control and flexibility.